# Jquery doesn't link, why?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="green"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('div').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
   $('div').click(function() {
       $(this).toggle(1000);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: you are using jQuery in the page but the library is not included in it

Comment: Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` before `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Add jQuery framework to your html head tag, before your own js which use jQuery:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```